# InstallService and UnInstallService doesn't show in intellisence

Tags: c#

I have a piece of code for installing or uninstalling a windows service.

```
internal class CFEServiceInstaller
{
    #region Private Variables
    private string _servicePath;
    private string _serviceName;
    private string _serviceDisplayName;
    #endregion Private Variables
    #region DLLImport
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpSCDB, int scParameter);
    [DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr SC_HANDLE, string lpSvcName, string lpDisplayName,
    int dwDesiredAccess, int dwServiceType, int dwStartType, int dwErrorControl, string lpPathName,
    string lpLoadOrderGroup, int lpdwTagId, string lpDependencies, string lpServiceStartName, string lpPassword);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern void CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr SCHANDLE);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int StartService(IntPtr SVHANDLE, int dwNumServiceArgs, string lpServiceArgVectors);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr SCHANDLE, string lpSvcName, int dwNumServiceArgs);
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int DeleteService(IntPtr SVHANDLE);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetLastError();
    #endregion DLLImport
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    /// <summary>
    /// This method installs and runs the service in the service control manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="svcPath">The complete path of the service.</param>
    /// <param name="svcName">Name of the service.</param>
    /// <param name="svcDispName">Display name of the service.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the process went thro successfully. False if there was any
    /// error.</returns>
    public bool InstallService(string svcPath, string svcName, string svcDispName)
    {
        #region Constants declaration.
        int SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
        int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;
        //int SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003;
        int SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001;
        int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0xF0000;
        int SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
        int SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x0002;
        int SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x0004;
        int SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x0008;
        int SERVICE_START = 0x0010;
        int SERVICE_STOP = 0x0020;
        int SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x0040;
        int SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x0080;
        int SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x0100;
        int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = (STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS |
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS |
        SERVICE_START |
        SERVICE_STOP |
        SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE |
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE |
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL);
        int SERVICE_AUTO_START = 0x00000002;
        #endregion Constants declaration.
        try
        {
            IntPtr sc_handle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);
            if (sc_handle.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                IntPtr sv_handle = CreateService(sc_handle, svcName, svcDispName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS, SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL, svcPath, null, 0, null, null, null);
                if (sv_handle.ToInt32() == 0)
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //now trying to start the service
                    int i = StartService(sv_handle, 0, null);
                    // If the value i is zero, then there was an error starting the service.
                    // note: error may arise if the service is already running or some other problem.
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("Couldnt start service");
                        return false;
                    }
                    //Console.WriteLine("Success");
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_handle);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
                //Console.WriteLine("SCM not opened successfully");
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// This method uninstalls the service from the service conrol manager.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="svcName">Name of the service to uninstall.</param>
    public bool UnInstallService(string svcName)
    {
        int GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
        IntPtr sc_hndl = OpenSCManager(null, null, GENERIC_WRITE);
        if (sc_hndl.ToInt32() != 0)
        {
            int DELETE = 0x10000;
            IntPtr svc_hndl = OpenService(sc_hndl, svcName, DELETE);
            //Console.WriteLine(svc_hndl.ToInt32());
            if (svc_hndl.ToInt32() != 0)
            {
                int i = DeleteService(svc_hndl);
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_hndl);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    CloseServiceHandle(sc_hndl);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Now I have to call InstallService in another class but it is not showing the method. See the image please.
[image]

Comment: Did you mean "intellisense"???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to make those methods static.